# Russlanddeutsch: Gibt es das für ein anderes Land?

Tags: adjective

In der Tagesschau hieß es, eines der bekanntesten Beispiele von Falschmeldungen sei wohl der *Fall Lisa*. Lisa ist ein **russlanddeutsches** Mädchen. <s>Damit ist höchstwahrscheinlich ein Abkömmling der Wolgadeutschen gemeint.</s>

Ist das ein Einzelfall? (Ich meine Russland, nicht die Fake News). 
Oder wäre es verständlich, falls jemand z.B. *polendeutsch* wäre (das heißt jemand, der beispielsweise Enkelkind von Deutschen der der ehemals deutschen Stadt Breslau ist).

Existiert denn der Begriff *Russlanddeutsch* nur deswegen, weil er sich der Häufigkeit halber durchsetzt?

Comment: Etwas, das nicht existiert, kann sich nicht durchsetzen. Es muss also erst existieren bevor es sich durchsetzt.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich heißt es in den Nachrichten nur deswegen *russlanddeutsch*, weil sich unter z.B. *bessarabiendeutsch* (das es als Begriff allerdings gibt) kein geographisch durchschnittlich Gebildeter etwas vorstellen kann - und es für die Nachricht auch vollkommen unerheblich ist. Die feiner abgestuften Begriffe wie *sudetendeutsch* sind uns geografisch näher.

Comment: Gegenbeispielsweise: Ether. Der hatte sich eine Weile durchgesetzt und den gibt es keinesfalls.

Answer (score 2):

Halbwegs gebräuchlich sind auch noch rumäniendeutsch für Donauschwaben und im historischen Kontext wolgadeutsch für die deutsche Volksgruppe, die später noch weiter weg an der kasachischen Grenze umgesiedelt wurde. Das sind die Russlanddeutschen, von denen aktuell gesprochen wird.

Comment: Es gibt auch *Ungarndeutsche*, siehe Wikipedia, und auch eine erkleckliche deutsche Minderheit in Tschechien, die erstaunlicherweise **nicht** Tschechiendeutsche genannt wird, sondern *Deutschböhmer*, *Deutschmährer* und *Sudetendeutsche*. Ähnlich heißt die verbliebene deutsche Minderheit in Polen nicht "Polendeutsche", sondern *Deutschschlesier*.

Comment: @tofro: Neben den Schlesiern gibt es in Polen auch noch Ostpreußen.

Answer (score 2):

In Wikipedia unter dem Titel: [Russlanddeutsche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russlanddeutsche) gibt es diese interessante Information.

> Es handelt sich um eine regional ursprünglich sehr verteilte Gruppe,
>   die nach dem Siedlungsort innerhalb des Russischen Zarenreiches
>   unterteilt werden in **Wolgadeutsche**, **Wolhyniendeutsche**, **Krimdeutsche**,
>   **Kaukasiendeutsche**, **Schwarzmeerdeutsche**, **Sibiriendeutsche.**

Comment: Gut zu wissen. Dementsprechend habe ich den Satz gestrichen.